# Array elements to integers

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings containing numbers:

```
array = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

I want to convert every string in the array to an integer.

`array.each { |n| n.to_i }` does not work, because

```
p array.inject(:+)
```

returns `"123"` (string) rather than `6` (integer)

Comment: If all you want is the sum, just do it in one operation: `array.reduce(0) { |t,n| t+n.to_i }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = ["1", "2", "3"]
new_array = array.map { |n| n.to_i }
p new_array.inject(:+)
=> 6
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks. I was unaware of the map method.

Comment: while this answer is correct surprisingly `Symbol.to_proc` is actually faster so `array.map(&:to_i)` will actually increase performance while performing the same operation

Answer (score 0):

one-line solution:

```
array.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
# => 6
```